# Define time out for node.js callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, callback

I have a callback in node.js with S3.

Here is the code:

```
FS.prototype.myfunc = function (base, url, size, callBackArg) {
    var s3ForHead = new AWS.S3({httpOptions:{timeout: 5000}});

    console.log("Define s3Forhead Object");

    s3ForHead.listObjects({
        "Prefix" : url,
        "Bucket" : S3_BUCKET
    }, function (err, data) {

        console.log("Callback is done");

        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
            callBackArg("404");
        } else {
            if (data.Contents.length > 0) {
                callBackArg("200");
            } else {
                callBackArg("404");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason, The listObjects freeze sometimes in the stage of listObjects.

Meaning, `Callback is done` isn't printed to the screen.

I want that after `5000ms`, if the callback doesn't return, I will return "404" with my callBackArg argument.

Is there any way to so it with node.js?

Comment: @Alexander: I get it as an argument in my function

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
FS.prototype.myfunc = function (base, url, size, callBackArg) {
    var s3ForHead = new AWS.S3({httpOptions:{timeout: 5000}});

    var failed = false; // failed flag
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        failed = true;   // set failed flag
        callback("404"); // callback with "404"
    }, 5000);

    console.log("Define s3Forhead Object");

    s3ForHead.listObjects({
        "Prefix" : url,
        "Bucket" : S3_BUCKET
    }, function (err, data) {

        console.log("Callback is done");

        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
            callBackArg("404");
        } else if (!failed) { // Check if not failed

            clearTimeout(timeout); // remove the timeout if the data is ready

            if (data.Contents.length > 0) {
                callBackArg("200");
            } else {
                callBackArg("404");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: micnic,your code will fail if the callback of listobjects fires before 5000ms.The "failed" variable will be false and callbkacArg(200) will be sent correctly.However after 5000ms your timeout function will call the callback("404") irrespective.Your code will only work when the listobjects callback runs after 5000ms.

Comment: So we need to set the boolean variable in the callback of listobjects and do the checking in the timeout function and not the  other way around

Comment: @harryy000, ah, forgot to add the `clearTimeout`, edited, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think setTimeout blocks the event loop,it just queues up the function for execution after x seconds.So you could use a variable to check if the callback is fired.Also you can call the setTimeout inside the FS.prototype func but after listobjects.

```
FS.prototype.myfunc = function(base, url, size, callBackArg) {
    var timeout = true;//will be true before the callback is fired
    var s3ForHead = new AWS.S3({
        httpOptions: {
            timeout: 5000
        }
    });
    console.log("Define s3Forhead Object");
    s3ForHead.listObjects({
        "Prefix": url,
        "Bucket": S3_BUCKET
    }, function(err, data) {
        timeout = 'false';//set to false here since callback is fired
        console.log("Callback is done");
        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
            callBackArg("404");
        } else {
            if (data.Contents.length > 0)
                callBackArg("200");
            else
                callBackArg("404");
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (timeout) return callback("404");//Only call 404 if callback is not fired
    }, 5000);
    console.log('see settimeout does not block');//settimeout does not block,it executes callback after x secs.
};
```